# How can I get my requests Session to retry automatically when there is a timeout?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to understand why my requests Session does not automatically retry when the request times out after the 20 seconds. I was under the impression that the retry settings that I configured would cause the Session to automatically retry if it times out, but I get the following exceptions instead:

```
# yada yada
socket.timeout: The write operation timed out  
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  
# yada yada
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', timeout('The write operation timed out',))
```

Below is a snippet of how I configure the Session object and make the request:

```
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

session = requests.Session()
settings = Retry( total = 10, backoff_factor = 0.1, status_forcelist = [ 500, 502, 503, 504 ] )                     
session.mount( "https://", HTTPAdapter( max_retries = settings ) )

resp = session.post( uploadAddress, files={"file": myFile}, timeout=20 )
```

I can't seem to find useful info about using the Retry object in conjunction with the timeout parameter in the official documentation, so maybe it just can't be done this simply.

Comment: So do you only want to post again when it timeout?

Comment: No, I want the post to automatically retry according to the Retry settings I have configured for the Session, and I am wondering if the timeout parameter I am passing to the post call is overriding these settings, or if there is a way to use both (i.e. wait 20 seconds, if needed, retry, wait 20 seconds, etc.).